# Neo4J poor performance for queries like (:A {id:123})-[:MYREL]->(:B)<-[:MYREL]-(:C) etc

Tags: database, neo4j, graph-databases, query-performance

I have a tree of nodes in my application, let's say it looks like this -

```
A 
  -> B
  -> C
     -> D
        -> E
```

Where A, B, C... are the nodes labels. I have a GUID of the root node, and I'd like to retrieve all possible nodes of the given types for this tree.

What I am doing is creating all possible paths in that tree, like {A -> B}, {A -> C}, {A -> C -> D} ... and concatenating them in one big query, using UNION ALL (sometimes it's about 100 UNION ALL statements), e.g:

`MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:B) UNION ALL
MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:C) UNION ALL
MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:C)->[:REL]->(:D) UNION ALL
RETURN path`

It works, but takes seconds even on a small dataset. I noticed that it is slow only first time, after that query takes 10-20 ms. Looks like query plan consumes most of the time, but unfortunately my trees are dynamic, all those paths are unique each time - looks like Neo4j just can't cache them.

I've profiled a subquery of my UNION ALL query (one path in the tree), and even this subquery takes 90 ms for the first run -

`MATCH path = (:PROVIDER {guid:'cafbf60e-612a-4c36-9337-50c26c941911'})<-[:REL]-(:ADDRESS)-[:REL]->(:ATTRIBUTE)-[:REL]->(:VALUE)-[:REL]->(:FIELD)<-[:REL]-(:TYPE)-[:REL]->(:CODE) RETURN path`

Why it is so bad? Can this subquery be optimized, or maybe the whole UNION ALL can be redesigned somehow?

I have index on `PROVIDER:guid`, dataset is about 800 nodes, this particular query returns 0 results.

Query profile result -

`Cypher version: CYPHER 3.2, planner: COST, runtime: INTERPRETED. 1 total db hits in 90 ms.`

Neo4J version: 3.2.5

[image]

Comment: Your example query isn't using UNION ALL. It seems like you're asking about two different queries. Please provide all necessary info on the queries you're running, and why you're using UNION ALL instead of a single non-union query for what you need. Your "100 UNION ALL" use case sounds like it can be simplified if we take a closer look.

Comment: Also, what do you really need out of the query? Do you really need paths to every reachable node from the start, or do you just need all reachable nodes? Depending on what you really need out of this query, we might be able to find a simpler way to get your desired results.

Comment: I've updated the question to provide UNION ALL example - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/49603677/revisions My goal is to load the whole tree from DB, having all the paths (labels and relations between them)

Comment: I'm not asking about different queries, just the whole UNION ALL and it's subquery (one path in the tree) - even subquery have a bad performance, and I'm wondering why? It is really simple, I'm providing the path in the graph, all the labels and indexes

Answer (score 0):

This is bad case for UNION ALL, you should look for alternatives.

Have you tried using [variable-length patterns](https://graphaware.com/graphaware/2015/05/19/neo4j-cypher-variable-length-relationships-by-example.html) yet? If you just want the entire tree, this should work, no need for UNION ALL at all:

```
MATCH path = (:PROVIDER {guid:'cafbf60e-612a-4c36-9337-50c26c941911'})-[:REL*]-() 
RETURN path
```

You may also want to double-check your indexes (run a PROFILE of this query and make sure it's using a node by index seek), as the query plan you provided is using a node by label scan.

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:B) UNION ALL
MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:C) UNION ALL
MATCH path = (:A {guid:'123456'})->[:REL]->(:C)->[:REL]->(:D) UNION ALL
RETURN path
```

does not seem to need a UNION ALL. Why not:

```
MATCH path=((n:A{guid:'123456'})-[:REL*0..2]->(m) return path
```

if you are looking for specific nodes, you could add that constraint:

```
MATCH path=((n:A{guid:'123456'})-[:REL*0..2]->(m) where m.{property:value}) in [{list}] return path
```

Also, as InverseFalcon notes, what do you really want in the results? That may require a somewhat different query.